# XCTest, XCTWaiter waiting for multiplie exceptions

Tags: swift, automated-tests, xctest

I'm trying to wait for one of two things to happen.

```
    let predicateOne = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    let predicateTwo = NSPredicate(format: "isHittable == true")
    let expOne = expectation(for: predicateOne, evaluatedWith: elementOne,handler: nil)
    let expTwo = expectation(for: predicateTwo, evaluatedWith: ElementTwo,handler: nil)
    let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expOne,expTwo], timeout: 5)
```

There are two elements elementOne and elementTwo. I want to know as soon as elementOne exists OR elementTwo is hittable. How can can I get from the XCTWaiter which element triggered it to stop waiting?

Comment: Why do you care which element stopped the waiter? Since you're waiting for both of them, it means you should not don't care which one is available first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, but XCTWaiter returns a [result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctwaiter/result) and you should observe this result, something like this

```
XCTAssertEqual(result, .completed)
```